# What is the upper bound on the error of the solution of a noise perturbed linear system $Mx=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $x$ be solution to the following linear system:

$$ Mx = b$$

and let $ \tilde{x}$ be the solution to the above linear system with some additive noise:

$$ M \tilde{x}= \tilde{b}$$

where $\tilde{b} = b + e$

let $\sigma_{min}(M)$ denote the smallest singular value of matrix $M$.

I was trying to verify **rigorously** why:

$$ \| x - \tilde{x} \| \leq \frac{ \| b - \tilde{b} \|}{\sigma_{min}(M)}$$

was true. However, I was unsure how to do it correctly.

This is what I have tried:

Notice that (if we assume a bound on the condition number, hence invertibility of M), then M is invertible and we get:

$$ \tilde{x}= M^{-1}\tilde{b} = M^{-1}(b+e) = x+M^{-1}e$$

Now $\| x - \tilde{x} \|$ is:

$$\| x - \tilde{x} \| = \| M^{-1}e \|$$

To relate the singular values of M to the equation above, lets bring in its SVD, $M^{-1} = (U \Sigma V^T)^{-1} = V \Sigma^{-1} U^T$:

$$\| x - \tilde{x} \| = \| M^{-1}e \| = \| V \Sigma^{-1} U^T e \| = \| \sum^{r}_{j=1} \frac{1}{\sigma_j} v_j u_j^T e\|$$

By triangle inequality:

$$ \| \sum^{r}_{j=1} \frac{1}{\sigma_j} v_j u_j^T e\| \leq \sum^{r}_{j=1} \| \frac{1}{\sigma_j} v_j u_j^T e\| $$

After this point a got a little stuck, however, I had a few ideas that looked promising but wasn't sure how to use them. It feels that if the singular vectors are orthonormal, then taking the norm yields 1 which together with the triangle inequality again could yield an upper bound of the sum of the reciprocal of the singular values? Seems like a true statement, however, might this upper bound to lose and its just the wrong direction for the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue from the stuck-point, since $v_j$'s are orthonormal, the Pythagorean theorem gives
$$
\left\|\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{1}{\sigma_j}v_ju_j^Te\right\|_2^2=
\left\|\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{u_j^Te}{\sigma_j}v_j\right\|_2^2
=\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{|u_j^Te|^2}{\sigma_j}\leq\frac{1}{\sigma_{\min}(M)}\sum_{j=1}^r|u_j^Te|^2.
$$
The last touch is due to 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^r|u_j^Te|^2=\|U^Te\|_2^2\leq\|U\|_2^2\|e\|_2^2\leq\|e\|_2^2.
$$

Comment: what happened from step 2 to 3? don't think I understand. Is that where you used the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, exactly there; there was also a "typo" which is fixed now. You can see, what you start with is a combination of orthogonal vectors $w_j:=(u_j^Te/\sigma_j)v_j$. Hence square of the norm of their sum is the sum of squares of their norms. The norm of $w_j$ is simply the magnitude of the scalar $u_j^Te/\sigma_j$ since $v_j$ is normalized.

Comment: last question and I think I got this, last line, from step 1 to 2. How did that happen?

Comment: @CharlieParker Note that $U^Te=\pmatrix{u_1^T\\\vdots \\u_r^T}e=\pmatrix{u_1^Te\\\vdots \\u_r^Te}$.

Comment: But for orthogonal matrices, $U^T U  = I$  not $U U^T $, you sure about your last tine?

Comment: @CharlieParker There was nothing said about the size of $U$ or $M$ but if the $r$ is generally smaller than the size of $M$ then of course we have only an inequality.

Comment: I actually liked your "invariant orthonormal" version a bit better, it was more intuitive (for me). What was wrong with it? I thought that vectors were (norm-2) size invariant wrt to orthonormal/unitary transformation.

Comment: I see your previous answer $e^T U^T U e = e^T e = \| e \|^2$ depended on the fact that $U^T U = U U^T = I$ which only holds for square (symmetric) matrices.

Comment: Ok, so your new answer is definitively more general, but it uses a property of l2 norms that I am not familiar with! Do you mind explaining it or providing a reference so I can learn about it? Thanks for all your help btw! I've learned a lot :)

Comment: @CharlieParker What property do you have in mind? $\|U^Te\|_2\leq\|U\|_2\|e\|_2$ follows from the submultiplicativity and the fact that $\|U^T\|_2=\|U\|_2$; if $U$ has orthonormal rows/columns, then $\|U\|_2=1$.